# Multiple Inheritance of variadic classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, variadic-templates

Can I do the below?

```
template<class D>
class A {};

template<class... Ds>
class B : public A<Ds>... {};
```

I am expecting the behaviour:

```
template<class D1, class D2>
class B : public A<D1>, public A<D2> {};
```

Comment: Have you tied that before asking the question?

Comment: @273K need to confirm if this works. Can't only based my answer on compiler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do the below?

Yes.

Inheriting from the class template is perfectly ok, given that you provide the necessary template parameters, which you've done.